# How can I add a new attributes to CSR x.509

Tags: python, openssl, csr

I'm trying to create a CSR x.509 certificate, and I want to add a new attributes that is not from the CSR attributes in python, for example; Industry and InvoiceType

So this is what I'm trying to do, piece of code:

```
from OpenSSL import crypto
 

def cert_gen(
    commonName="commonName",
    serialNumber=1234,
    organizationUnitName="organizationUnitName",
    organizationName="organizationName",
    countryName="NT",
    industry="Industry",
    invoiceType = "InvoiceType",
    Pri_FILE = "private.key",
    Pub_FILE = "public.key",
    CERT_FILE="certificate.crt"):
 
    # create a key pair
    k = crypto.PKey()
    k.generate_key(crypto.TYPE_RSA, 4096)
   
    cert = crypto.X509()
    cert.get_subject().CN = commonName
    cert.get_subject().C = countryName
    cert.get_subject().L = location
    cert.get_subject().O = organizationName
    cert.get_subject().OU = organizationUnitName
    cert.get_subject().I = industry
    cert.get_subject().IN =invoiceType
    cert.set_serial_number(serialNumber)

    cert.set_issuer(cert.get_subject())

    cert.set_pubkey(k)
    cert.sign(k, 'sha512')

    with open(CERT_FILE, "wt") as f:
        f.write(crypto.dump_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert).decode("utf-8"))
    with open(Pri_FILE, "wt") as f:
        f.write(crypto.dump_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, k).decode("utf-8"))
    with open(Pub_FILE, "wt") as f:
        f.write(crypto.dump_publickey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, k).decode("utf-8"))

cert_gen()
```

I see some people said something about that the extensions is needed but I don't found any information about how to do it.

[And this is the output that I want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKxuX.png)